# List of AspNetCore Culture cookie

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, culture

I need a prebuilt list of AspNetCore.Culture cookie values. For example:

> c=en|uic=en

or

> c=tr|uic=TR

I am coding the ability to have dynamic cultures via the database that the user can control from the website.

If there has any best practices please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes

Comment: To make it more clear, based on the list Polish would be like "c=pl|uic=PL" ? and what would be for Arabic ? "c=ar|uic=ar"

Comment: Yes, it is like that if you want to set same culture (c) and ui culture (uic).